# Getting index of element in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following html element in a table row:

```
<a class="btn small small-red-button" ng-click="addTicket(d, schedule.schedule_id )" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus state"></i> <span class="text">Add Ticket</span></a>
```

Now based on some value the row is repeated using ng-repeat in angularjs(nothing to do with my question)

However now i am trying to get the index of a repeated element using jquery when that element is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn.small", function() {
            alert($(this).index());
        });
```

but no matter how many times that element is repeated or which one i click the index always pops up as 0. Can somebody please tell me why?

Comment: I beg to differ: http://jsfiddle.net/ym8fev5o/1/ -- Please provide a reproducible problem.

Comment: You probably want `$(".btn.small").index(this)` as the buttons aren't siblings, but in different rows.

Comment: @Juhana.. Sorry for that. Removed that

Comment: Actually @Adeneo's answer solved my issue for me, it works just fine now.  Would have marked it as the right answer if it wasn't a comment.

Comment: You mentioned "trying to get the index of EACH repeated element" in your post. I think that confused the guy that answered it.

Comment: Oh okay i see my mistake, my bad, i'll change that even though i already have my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for closing this question as per @adeneo comment

**Code**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn.small", function() {
   alert($(".btn.small").index(this));
});
```